# Running two shell script in the same shell using python scripting

Tags: python, shell

I am calling two shell scripts using python script
My python script: test.py

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['/usr//bin/tcsh', '-c', 'source set_env.csh'])

subprocess.Popen(['/usrl/bin/tcsh', '-c', 'source ech_env.csh'])
```

code for set_env.csh

```
#!/usr/bin/csh
setenv IP_ROOT $cwd
```

code for ech_env.csh

```
#!/usr/bin/csh

echo $IP_ROOT
```

The output will be current working directory path which is store in $cwd . I am getting output as

```
IP_ROOT:Undefined variable.
```

Please any one know how can I execute set_env.csh and ech_env.csh in the same shell.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/tcsh', '-c', 'source set_env.csh && source ech_env.csh'])
```

You need to do everything in a single shell process, so that the environment variables persist between the two scripts.

Comment: Is any other way other than this ? because i have more than 20 scripts need to be run in a same opened shell, is any possibility ?

Comment: @deepa: sure, you can write a single wrapper script which runs all of them, then invoke that from Python.

Comment: hi i am facing issue, that is subprocess.Popen(['/usr//bin/tcsh', '-c', 'source set_env.csh'])

subprocess.Popen(['/bin/tcsh', '-c', 'source ech_env.csh'])

Comment: in that one script is running other one not running. if i do

Comment: subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/tcsh', '-c', 'source set_env.csh && source ech_env.csh']) not working can u tell how to connect these two

Comment: as i mentioned above one is /bin/csh and other /usr/bin/tcsh , one script not executing in subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/tcsh', '-c', 'source set_env.csh && source ech_env.csh']), please can u help me , how tomake connectivity if it returns in /bin/csh or usr/bin/tsch?

Comment: First you said it was working fine.  Now there are lots more questions.  I'm confused.  Maybe it's time to create a new question with a clear problem statement?

Comment: is it anyway to connect csh script and tsch script using python? but i want these two script have to run in same shell. Please help me... if both script belongs to tsch it will works fine. if one is csh script and other tsch script it wont work

Comment: If you need to run two scripts in two different languages, then no, you cannot run them in a single shell, by definition.  You should update one of the scripts to use the same language as the other, maybe.